# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supertype found on query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Integer SlNo;

  @Id
  private Long projectNo;

  private Date projectDate;
}
```

and in DAO class

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> countQ = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Project> empCount = countQ.from(Project.class);
countQ.select(cb.count(empCount));

TypedQuery<Long> countquery = entityManager.createQuery(countQ);// error in this line
```

I am getting exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supertype found` in the above line. How can I resolve or workaround this issue? Looks like there is a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7216), are there any solution to this?

I am using `Hibernate 4.1.0.Final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using `@EmbeddedId` in Entity class and `@Embeddable` in Primary Key class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project {
@Column(name = "SL_NO" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer SlNo;
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NO" , insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long projectNo;
private Date projectDate;

@EmbeddedId
ProjectPK projectPK;
```

and Primary Key class

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectPK implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "SL_NO")
private Integer SlNo;
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NO")
private Long projectNo; 

//with hashCode and equals implementation
```

Answer (score 0):

for the case Using @EmbeddedId, here is my solution. This code I have written in one class itself, in Entity class.

- Class MyEntity - It is my actual Entity class for my table. "OtherFields" are those fields which are not part of primary key.
- Class MyEntityPrimaryKeys   - It is the class made for my composite key which makes a primary key for my "MyEntity" class. Here ROLLNO and AGE together makes a primary key.

MyEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable")
public class MyEntity extends GenericPersistableEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId 
    MyEntityPrimaryKeys id;//Composite Primary key

    //Composite fields can be declared here for getter and setters
    @Column(name = "ROLLNO")
    private Long RollNo;

    //Composite fields can be declared here for getter and setters
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Long age;

    @Column(name = "OtherFields"
    private Long OtherFields;

    //getter and setters comes here
}



@Embeddable
 class MyEntityPrimaryKeys  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ROLLNO")
    Long RollNo;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    Long age;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder();
        hcb.append(RollNo);
        hcb.append(age);
        return hcb.toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof MyEntityPrimaryKeys)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyEntityPrimaryKeys that = (MyEntityPrimaryKeys) obj;
        EqualsBuilder eb = new EqualsBuilder();
        eb.append(RollNo, that.RollNo);
        eb.append(age, that.age);
        eb.append(tonMonth, that.tonMonth);
        eb.append(tonYear, that.tonYear);
        return eb.isEquals();
    }
}
```